# Display current number of Facebook group members using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook-group

Is there a way to display the current number of members of my [Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/arabiccafe/) on a SquareSpace code block (which only accepts HTML and JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally.

You can use Facebook Graph to accomplish what you want. Using an ordinary HTTPS request, I got this JSON-formatted results :

```
{
   "id": "165227436975532",
   "about": "Salon de Th\u00e9 style traditionnelle ..!!",
   "can_post": false,
   "category": "Restaurant/Cafe",
   "category_list": [
      {
         "id": "203462172997785",
         "name": "Tea Room"
      }
   ],
   "checkins": 66,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": "476669145831358",
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 54,
      "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpt1/v/t1.0-9/11536065_476669145831358_6075091507244297763_n.jpg?oh=7c6940ee3f2566884609fc59da224b67&oe=563A1B1D",
      "id": "476669145831358"
   },
   "has_added_app": false,
   "is_community_page": false,
   "is_published": true,
   "likes": 1246,
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/arabiccafe",
   "location": {
      "city": "Sousse",
      "country": "Tunisia",
      "latitude": 35.864546,
      "longitude": 10.5988045,
      "street": "Hammem Sousse",
      "zip": "4011"
   },
   "name": "Arabica Cafe",
   "parking": {
      "lot": 0,
      "street": 0,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "phone": "21770198",
   "talking_about_count": 6,
   "username": "arabiccafe",
   "were_here_count": 66
}
```

In order to get these info, you can use a normal XHR request (or jQuery.ajax if you use jQuery) and make a GET request to this URL :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/arabiccafe?access_token={your_token}
```

You can generate a token following [these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) directives.

Comment: Thanks Erik! So what would be the js code that I could throw into the SquareSpace machine?